# Get second string in a list of strings

Tags: google-bigquery, extract

| ID | Names (datatype string) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"Sigit, S.E","Chandra Kirana","Moehammad Taufan","Linda Widjaja","Hartono"} |
| 2 | WAWAN||Asep||Eko Haryanto||Sarah |
| 3 | {"Arief Ardiansyah","Paulus Santoso","Ivan Surya","Hartono"} |

Hello, I want to extract the second name on the list above in GBQ.

I came up with:

```
coalesce(split(names,',')[safe_ordinal(2)],split(names,'||')[safe_ordinal(2)])
```

How ever this doesn't work properly for **ID = 1** because it gives me the result "**S.E**" when the correct extraction should be "**Chandra Kirana**"

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: have you tried `split(names,'","')`?

Comment: The best solution is to normalize your data so you don't put lists in values.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether a comma is present, it splits the name string and extracts the second element using SAFE_ORDINAL:

```
  TRIM(SPLIT(names, IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(names, ','), ',', '||'))[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)]) AS SecondName
```